# What are the actual SDL2 hardware requirements?

Tags: sdl

I just can't find them anywhere. The most important part for me is the hardware acceleration, and I have no idea if there is a performance or openGL version compatibility requirement that the video card has to follow.

Answer (score 2):

The minimum system requirements will depend alot more on the application that you are writing than what SDL2 does.

If you just create a standard window and render SDL will use what it can find and what it thinks is best either OpenGL, OpenGL ES, Direct3D or use the old style software rendering for machines that can't do any of the other. So if a computer can support an OS that SDL runs on then you will almost always (I just said almost since there can possible be exceptions) be able to run these type of apps (Video card not a requirement, but having one will greatly increase programs drawing speed).

You can also be creating a OpenGL application directly and then it depends on what type of context you are making what the video card has to support.

You can find most of the information here: http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.fcg/MigrationGuide
under the Video section. It's actually how to port from 1.2 to 2.0 , but it explains the new Video Pipeline pretty well.

Hope thats what you were looking for.

Comment: You seem to have trailed off there at the end.

Comment: Oops. Fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that SDL was able to use D3D.
Anyway, I had a reason behide this question - I wrote a minimal code (both in SDL and SFML) that rendered a single sprite and pushed the FPS to the title bar. It was running faster or slower on different setups, but it was always in thousands of FPS. But I've found one computer which took half a second to draw a single frame! The computer was quite old (Geforce 5xxx), but at least it could run Vista.. I had no idea what could be causing this so I thought there may be some incompatibility problems that I had no idea about.

Comment: So my real question should be: if the SDL/SFML program runs absolutely terribly on one specific setup (which handles some simple games without hiccups) and assuming the program itself is correct and as simple as possible - what should I even start with to find a possible reason behind this?

Comment: Are you sure it's the drawing that's taking forever? (Probably is, but can you check with just timing between draw calls and not system stuff which can block like title updates etc.)